How to make get uniform scales across heat maps?
I am trying to illustrate the transformation of a data set in R. The goal is to show that an applied formula has compacted the distribution of data points and increased the density, so I want to show the heat map of and old plot vs a new plot.
So, I take my two data frames:
old_df
which when processed becomes this:
new_df
So, when I plot my old plot using this code:
ggplot(old_df,aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(aes(),size = .02, alpha = .1)

ggsave("1.svg")


and now the new_df plotted using the same gives me
ggplot(new_df,aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(aes(),size = .02, alpha = .1)

ggsave("2.svg")


So, the formula is doing what we want it to. But adding some color would be good.
This is where I tried:
density <- MASS::kde2d(old_df$x, old_df$y)
ix <- findInterval(old_df$x, density$x)
iy <- findInterval(old_df$y, density$y)
ii <- cbind(ix, iy)
old_df$signal_density <- density$z[ii]

ggplot(old_df,aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(aes(color=signal_density),size = .02, alpha = .1) +
scale_color_viridis()

ggsave("3.svg")


So far so good. Now I need the second plot
density <- MASS::kde2d(new_df$x, new_df$y)
ix <- findInterval(new_df$x, density$x)
iy <- findInterval(new_df$y, density$y)
ii <- cbind(ix, iy)
new_df$signal_density <- density$z[ii]

ggplot(new_df,aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(aes(color=signal_density),size = .02, alpha = .1) +
scale_color_viridis()

ggsave("4.svg") 


The issue here is that the legend on the two plots use the same color but different scaling. For example, yellow in old is 300 but yellow in new is 1000 - that is confusing to the end viewer.
So, I am trying to make the scales uniform.
Is there a way to have the two signal_density estimation to have the same scale?
I think this might be less a matter of syntax and more a matter of the underlying calculus perhaps. What am I missing?

Untested: density <- MASS::kde2d(c(old_df$x, new_df$x), c(old_df$y, new_df$y)) will put all density values within the same ranges.
